# KnockoutJS: How to update view model after a user copy'n'paste into a text field?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am working on a website that auto populates search result in a table after user entered some text in the input text box (similar to google instant search).

I managed to get knockout js to update view model as user enters information by adding

`valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`

into my data-bind attribute, however, I also need to handle the case where user right click and paste some text into the textbox so I tried:

`valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown','mouseup']`

but that didn't work and when I tried to read the value of the text box through the view model **I kept getting the old value until I tab out of the input text box**.

Anyone know how can I fix this?

Oscar

Comment: Knockout now has a new binding for this.  See my answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19957131/143739

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use valueUpdate:'input'. I have testet it to work in Opera, Firefox and Chrome. I'm on a Linux box, so I can't test it in IE. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJCQq/4/)

UPDATE: I have now testet it in IE8, and it doesn't work. But using the following seems to work.

```
valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']
```

Thanks to Michael Best for his comment about this :) I have updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJCQq/4/)

UPDATE okt 2014: As kzh mention in a comment below, in one of the later versions of Knockout.js the textInput binding was added. This binding handles this scenario and has build in browser quirks handling 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html

Comment: `valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']` covers all the bases (except deleting using the mouse in IE9 which doesn't fire any event and so can't be handled).

Comment: There is now the textInput binding.

Answer (score 10):

### New Way

Instead of:

```
data-bind="value: myValue, valueUpdate: ['input', 'textchange']"
```

One can now use the [textInput binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html):

```
data-bind="textInput: myValue"
```

From the documentation:

> The `textInput` binding links a text box (`<input>`) or text area (`<textarea>`) with a viewmodel property, providing two-way updates between the viewmodel property and the element’s value. Unlike the `value` binding, `textInput` provides instant updates from the DOM for all types of user input, including autocomplete, drag-and-drop, and clipboard events.

### Old Way

```
valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']
```

Does not work in IE9 if you want to support <kbd>RightMouseClick</kbd> → <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>RightMouseClick</kbd> → <kbd>Cut</kbd>.

The solution I came up with involves using jQuery and a jQuery plugin called [jQuery Splendid Textchange](http://benalpert.com/2013/06/18/a-near-perfect-oninput-shim-for-ie-8-and-9.html). After you have both the jQuery and the plugin scripts loaded, you can happily use the 'textchange' event.

```
valueUpdate: 'textchange'
```

But, I may one day stop supporting bad browsers, so I have this:

```
valueUpdate: ['input', 'textchange']
```

Here is a fiddle I made for testing this and other events: http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/w3ErR/

N.B. If you are using requirejs, jquery may have to be a hard dependency of knockout for this to work properly all the time.

Comment: "New Way" (i.e. textInput binding) starts working from v3.2.0 of Knockout, see http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/08/18/knockout-3-2-0-released. So if you use older version, it's probably time to update.