# Knockout.js bind slider range input

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, slider

I'm trying to bind an [Input Range Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_range.asp) with Knockout.js. The value binding seems to works well but I can't find a way to update the observable while dragging the slider. The observable is updated only when I release the mouse, giving a bad experience since I'm creating a volume slider.

I've tried every [valueUpdate](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) option without any result. They seems made just for text input.

```js
var ViewModel = function() { 
    this.rangeValue = ko.observable(50);
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: rangeValue"/>
<input type="range" data-bind="value: rangeValue, valueUpdate: 'change'"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging

Comment: @RoyJ so, you know a way to set valueUpdate to 'input' or something like that?

Comment: @RoyJ nevermind, valueUpdate: 'input' seems to exist even if not documented. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging), you need to listen to the oninput event to get the new value while dragging.

A fast Google search resulted in Knockout.js [supporting valueUpdate: 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109339/knockoutjs-how-to-update-view-model-after-a-user-copynpaste-into-a-text-field) even if not documented.

```js
var ViewModel = function() { 
    this.rangeValue = ko.observable(50);
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: rangeValue"/>
<input type="range" data-bind="value: rangeValue, valueUpdate: 'input'"/>
```

Comment: It's documented here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#Parameters
"Note that this event is only raised by reasonably modern browsers (e.g., IE 9+)."

Comment: @RoyJ I really don't know why I didn't see it before.. thank you!